# Understanding this C syntax for ARM Cortex-M interrupt vector table definition

Tags: c, gcc, interrupt, startup, cortex-m

I'm currently looking at some startup code for an ARM Cortex-M microcontroller written by someone else. The entire file can be found in this [Github repo](https://github.com/ataradov/mcu-starter-projects/blob/master/stm32g071/startup_stm32g0.c).

It does stuff like setting up the stack pointer and initalizing the `.data` and `.bss` sections appropriately using some for loops which are straightforward.

I'm struggling to understand the syntax used to define the interrupt vector table:

```
#define DUMMY __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("irq_handler_dummy")))

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void irq_handler_reset(void);
DUMMY void irq_handler_nmi(void);
DUMMY void irq_handler_hard_fault(void);
// etc. 

extern int main(void);

extern void _stack_top(void);
// etc.

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
__attribute__ ((used, section(".vectors")))
void (* const vectors[])(void) =
{
  &_stack_top,                   // 0 - Initial Stack Pointer Value

  // Cortex-M0+ handlers
  irq_handler_reset,             // 1 - Reset
  irq_handler_nmi,               // 2 - NMI
  irq_handler_hard_fault,        // 3 - Hard Fault
  // etc.
};
```

The `__attribute__` definition for GCC is clear and I've found the answer to what it does in the official documentation: [GCC Function attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.1.0/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes).

I still have no idea how to parse and put in to words what this syntax means

```
void (* const vectors[])(void)
```

Can somebody help me understand what all that syntax unpacks to or represents?

Comment: It means "[declare vectors as array of const pointer to function (void) returning void](https://cdecl.org/?q=void+%28*+const+vectors%5B%5D%29%28void%29)"

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that site!

Comment: There are great answers here. You might find [cdecl](https://cdecl.org) amusing (or not!).  It says: _declare vectors as array of const pointer to function (void) returning void._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A vector table is essentially just an array of ISR addresses. Which translated to C can be regarded as an array of function pointers. Creating the vector table as an array of function pointers is quite common.

What makes Cortex M a special snowflake is that it loads the stack pointer from flash through hardware, rather than the programmer setting it up manually in run-time. The first item of the vector table contains the value of the initial stack pointer - it is actually *not* a function address. Therefore some manner of hack is necessary. The `_stack_top` will likely boil down to some stack address set in a linker script. Your code will never use this item directly, it's just there so that the stack gets set correctly at boot-up.

Apart from that one, the rest are just normal function pointers to ISRs. Since an ISR takes no parameters and returns to value, the syntax of an ISR function pointer  is:

```
void (*name) (void)
```

An array of such function pointers is declared as:

```
void (*name [n]) (void)
```

Where `n` can optionally be used to express array size.

`__attribute__ ((used, section(".vectors")))` is just to place the array at a specific address, in this case from 0 and upwards. You can check the linker script and you'll find `.vectors` there.

We want this vector table to get loaded in flash ROM as read-only data. Therefore we want the pointers to be read-only, not what they point at. This is achieved by placing `const` on the right side of the `*` (same rule applies for normal object pointers too):

```
void (*const vectors[])(void)
```

We could have written this much more readable if a `typedef` had been used:

```
typedef void isr_vector_t (void);
...

isr_vector_t* const vectors[] = { ... };
```

Comment: This is a great answer that not only answers the syntax question but also puts it nicely in to context of Arm Cortex-M startup code!

Answer (score 2):

`vectors` is an array of of const function pointers which take and return `void`.

`_stack_top` isn't a function pointer, it's the address of the top of the stack, but for the cortex m, that is always the first element in the vector table.

The Cortex M architecture, and the implementation of it you're using defines the order of, and placement of the vector table. This code is some syntactic sugar to generate the table and place it in the correct location.

Comment: Thank you! I simply wasn't familiar with C function pointers but now I think I've got it.

Answer (score 1):

```
              vectors             -- vectors
              vectors[]           -- is an array of
      * const vectors[]           --   const pointer to
     (* const vectors[])(    )    --   function taking
     (* const vectors[])(void)    --     no parameters
void (* const vectors[])(void)    --   returning void
```

IOW, each `vectors[i]` is a pointer to a function; the functions being pointed to are specified in the initializer:

```
vectors[1] == irq_handler_reset,             // 1 - Reset
vectors[2] == irq_handler_nmi,               // 2 - NMI
vectprs[3] == irq_handler_hard_fault,        // 3 - Hard Fault
```

The `const` after the `*` means you can't update `vector[i]` after it has been initialized; IOW, you can't set `vectors[1]` to point to a function other than `irq_handler_reset`.

```
const T *p;  // you can update p to point to different objects, but
             // you cannot write to the pointed-to objects

T const *p;  // same as above

T * const p = some_addr; // you can write a new value to the object at
                         // some_addr, but you can't write a new value
                         // to p.
```

Answer (score 0):

`void (* const vectors[])(void)`

it is a definition and declaration of the **const array of function pointers** referencing function which takes no arguments and does not return any value.

It is initialized with references to the interrupt handlers (functions) defined in the source code. The first value takes the address of the symbol `_stack_top` defined in the linker script. This value will set the initial stack pointer when the micro boots.

Functions having `weak` linkage can be replaced by other function, without producing linker errors.